# workflow custom service host using service activation

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to add a custom service host to a workflow hosted in IIS using the service activations tag in the web.config. However I keep getting this error:

BuildManager returned an invalid compiled string for the virtual path /DefaultTest/TestWorkflow.xamlx.

my web.config looks like this:

> serviceActivations
>        add service="~/TestWorkflow.xamlx" relativeAddress="TestWorkflow.xamlx" factory="ServiceFactory.TestWorkflowServiceHost"
>   serviceActivations

If I set a break point in the constructor of the custom service host, it hits it, and the exception is thrown on the base.CreateServiceHost line.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe the leading ~/ in the service attribute is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<add factory="ServiceFactory.TestWorkflowServiceHost"
             relativeAddress="./TestWorkflow.xamlx"
             service="TestWorkflow.xamlx"/>
```